# How do I disable Metro bundler logs in react-native 0.60+

Tags: react-native

Since version 0.60 my `console.log()` goes to the bundler and its kinda annoying, is there a way to eliminate this behavior and let `console.log()` populate only on the debugger?

Please help me out with it.

[image]

Comment: Hmm wired, I have an RN 0.60+ its log in the debugger

Comment: @DevASI know, I added a capture to show the behavior

Comment: Try to run your app in android is still log in bundler?

Comment: @DevASIt only logs on iOS, android is clean.

Comment: Hmm, which RN version you insure the log not appear in the bundle?

Comment: @DevAS, We are on 0.61.4

Comment: Did you find a solution?